# Add predefined validator to a custom component in Angular

Tags: angular, validation, components

I'm developing a custom component to be used with forms in Angular. I'm implementing the `ControlValueAccessor` interface and it works great.

However, my component, has no reason to be used without `required` validator (it's a CAPTCHA), so all invocations of the component will have to specify `required` validator.

Is it possible to somehow embed this validator right into my component, so it will be always applied to it when used with `ngModel` and forms (both template-based and reactive ones)?

---

Clarification. Consider the example:

```html
<my-captcha [(ngModel)]="firstCaptcha" required></my-captcha>

<my-captcha [(ngModel)]="secondCaptcha" required></my-captcha>

<my-captcha [(ngModel)]="thirdCaptcha" required></my-captcha>
```

All invocations of `MyCaptcha` component above will have to use the `required` attribute in order for required validator to be applied to the form control.

Is it possible to invoke my custom controller without specifying the `required` attribute explicitly, but nevertheless have the validator applied to it? Like this:

```html
<my-captcha [(ngModel)]="captchaValue"></my-captcha>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit unfocused but, what do you mean with *required validator*? You mean the `required` attribute?

Comment: Yes, I mean that the value of the component must be provided, otherwise it's considered invalid. Angular solves this with `required` attribute in template-based forms.

Comment: I'm currently in a similar situation. Is it an option to use reactive forms?
Everything I found so far which might help has been done with reactive forms

Comment: I think the solution should be cross-compatible between the reactive and template forms.

Answer (score 0):

> all invocations of the component will have to specify required
>   validator

This triggered the idea of using and `abstract class` and `extend` it.

So, the way to *embed* the `required` validator to all your *Form Components* could be something like this:

```
export abstract class FormValidationClass implements ControlValueAccessor {
     // Implement your validation methods for your standard form including required validator

    protected formModel:<any>;        

    protected constructor() {
    }

    public requiredValidatorMethod() { 
        // Do stuff here with formModel, for example 
    }
}
```

And, where you actually create your component that will have a Form:

```
export class UserFilter extends FormValidationClass implements OnInit {

      protected formModel:<any>;

      this.requiredValidatorMethod (this.formModel);
}
```

So, as long as your classes declare `protected formModel` and `extends FormValidationClass` you will be able to use the methods within `FormValidationClass` and avoid having to add specific logic each time for each component that has a form.

That would be my way of *embeding* logic to all components that contain a form, in this case, embed the `required` validator to all the components that contain forms that need to be validated.

Hope it helps or that is at least useful! Let me know how it goes!

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for taking your time and writing the answer, however, I think that you have misunderstood my question. I've clarified it a bit. I'm talking not about reusing the component to define another components, but about adding the the validator to the component itself, not to it's invocation. And by invocation I mean it's single usage in the template.

Comment: Right, I think I understood. Take a look at this: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html#!#component-template Makes validation in code and attribute `required` is not needed *(he keeps it for styling purposes)*.

Comment: Regarding your link they are not encapsulating the validator inside of the custom component, they just move it from `required` attribute in template-based forms to a `Validators.required` symbol in reactive forms. But they still have to reference it.